# What is the best way to embed/nest multiple forms in rails simple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested-forms

I have a set of models that do the following:

1) A gallery has many images and belongs to a book

```
belongs_to :books
has_many :images
accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
```

// gallery controller

```
 class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_gallery, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @galleries = Gallery.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
  end

  def edit
  end
  def create
    @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
    @gallery.destroy
  end

  private
    def set_gallery
      @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    end
    def gallery_params
      params.require(:gallery).permit(:name, :book_id)
    end
end
```

2) Images belong to a gallery

```
belongs_to :gallery
    has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

// images controller

3) A book has one gallery

```
belongs_to :author
has_one :gallery

accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'nested_form'
```

In the form for the gallery I have got simple_fields_for and I have generated the form fields in there for the images to upload as these need to be multiple amounts to create the gallery like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@gallery, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :book_id %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :image do |a| %>
        <%#= f.input :picture %>
        <%#= a.file_field :file %>
        <%= f.input_field :file, as: :file, multiple: true, name: 'gallery[image]' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then in my book form where I create a book I have got a form where I want to nest the gallery form so I can add a gallery for each book creation. For some reason it does not seem to work and I keep getting errors:

```
undefined method `simple_nested_form_for' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x00000104d52640
```

The form is below.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@book, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>    
<%= f.simple_nested_form_for (@gallery) do |t| %>
    <%= t.simple_fields_for :gallery do |t| %>
    <%= render 'galleries/form' %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

These errors seem to be due to it not finding that method, I have restarted the server twice and I still get the same error.

The problem I am having is getting the gallery inside the book itself so I can create the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to include form inside form. i.e you have `<%= simple_form_for(@gallery, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>` under `<%= simple_form_for(@book, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>`.

You should have only one instance of form at once. Other should be like `<%= t.simple_fields_for :xyz do |t| %>`.

So remove `<%= simple_form_for(@gallery, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>` from your gallery form. If you need any other help you can follow ryan railscasts for nested forms. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 & http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2 .

For simple form in nested mode follow https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models